# Error on contract constructor - CompilerError: Stack too deep, try removing local variables

Tags: solidity, compilation

I have the following constructor on a contract:

```
constructor(
    string name,
    string symbol,
    uint8 tokenResolution,
    string defaultUnderlying,
    uint maturityTimestamp,
    uint rate,
    uint8 rateResolution,
    Rates.YieldFrequency yieldFrequency,
    Rates.DayCount dayCount,
    Rates.RateType rateType
) public
    Bond(maturityTimestamp, rate, rateResolution, yieldFrequency, dayCount, rateType)
    BaseToken(name, symbol, tokenResolution, defaultUnderlying)
{
}
```

And when I try to compile it I get this message:

> CompilerError: Stack too deep, try removing local variables.
>    ... maturityTimestamp ... 
>        ^---------------^